# How backup files with logrotate and Amazon S3?

Tags: linux, logging, amazon-s3, logrotate, s3cmd

I would like to create a new standard of two things: 
how long would be generated and be rotated the logs generated by my applications ?
 
how to transfer the logs to Amazon S3, as a backup server ?.

I was thinking in use logrotate, to rotate and compress my daily files this way:

```
{filename}-{year}-{month}-{day}-{r-months}.gz
```

The `r-months` variable means `remain-months`, for how many months the file should remain in S3, files older than that should be removed.

A friend of mine, give the idea I should `compress the logs daily` (in the new format proposed above) , after that these files should be sent to our bucket in Amazon S3.
Then `files older than 7 days should be removed by logrotate`(cause they are in S3 already).

Nowadays, our applications use `log4j` and others to generate logs.

1) Should we disable the versions logs, generated by our application and handle only with logrotate ? 
2) In your opinion did you think this could crash some application ? 
3) This new format of log, is a good one ?
4) And how send the files to S3 ? Now, I'm using `s3cmd`, did you recommend me another tool ?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your question #4:

You can mount S3 bucket as a local partition and work with S3 files as they were located on your server's filesystem. There are [a number](https://code.google.com/p/s3fs/) of [good](https://github.com/iij/s3fuse-fvs) Open Source tools available.

But from my side I would recommend you to take a look at my project: [RioFS](https://github.com/skoobe/riofs), a userspace filesystem to mount Amazon S3 buckets. Project's goals and the main advantages comparing to other similar tools are: simplicity, the speed of operations and a bugs-free code.

Currently the project is in the “beta” state, but it's been running on several high-loaded fileservers for quite some time ([RioFS](https://github.com/skoobe/riofs) provides there an access to S3 located files to ftp / sftp servers).

We are building a community around our project and are seeking for more people to join our project to discuss future plans and help with the testing. From our side we offer a quick bugs fix and will listen to your requests to add new features.

A quick how-to:

You could mount a bucket using the following command (assuming you have installed RioFS and have exported AWSACCESSKEYID and AWSSECRETACCESSKEY environment variables):

`riofs http://s3.amazonaws.com your_bucket_name /path/to/localfolder`

(please refer to project's description and run `riofs --help` to get help with command line arguments)

Please note that the project is still in the development, there could be still a number of bugs left.
If you find that something doesn't work as expected: please fill an issue report on the project's GitHub page.

Hope it helps and we are looking forward to seeing you joined our community !